# Check for valid partly hashed string

Tags: regex, hash, md5, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using regex for checking that a GDPR classified  column has been MD5 hashed.

Currently I'm using

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$
```

on columns that are fully hashed. However, we also have variations on partly hashed columns where we left out the the first leading digits on a phone number or a Zipcode. I.e.:

```
60025|f0fa4d4d9962bb113d92fe0eeb78d86b
```

I haven't managed to figure out how to apply the expression on the part after the pipe. I have tried to use `[^|]*$` to the expression but got stuck.

Would very much appreciate to get some advice on how to check for a hashed string in different combinations of hashed part like the above and i.e for email addresses where we keep the @-sign and the domain. The code is executed on Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I'm using ^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$
> how to check for a hashed string in different combinations

If you drop the anchors `^` and `$` you'll get also matches in the middle of a string. If you want to rule out longer hex sequences, you can use `\b` (word boundary) instead.

Comment: Great! I'll test this!

Answer (score 0):

You want to match hashes either from start of string or a pipe till the end of string.

That means, you can use

```sql
(^|[|])[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$
```

where

- `(^|[|])` - a group matching either the string start position (`^`) or (`|`) a pipe (`[|]`)
- `[0-9a-fA-F]{32}` - thirty-two alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kVMu7x/1).

Comment: Thank you! This put me on the right path! After some some tinkering and think I found out to test the whole string including to test that we manged to get the first digits right. I have now the following: ^?[0-9]*[|][0-9a-fA-F]{32}$

Comment: @mist Then you need `^([0-9]+[|])?[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$`.